# MS Excel: how to sum scientific notation excluding bracketted variance values looking like X.XXE-01 (XX.XXE-01)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, scientific-notation

I have cells of data in excel formatted as follows:

[image: image of cell formatting in excel]

*There is a need to have both the number and bracketted number in the same cell.*

I wish to create four more cells containing the percentage contribution of each cell to the sum of the non-backetted numbers.

I.e the sum in the first new cell would need to be 3e-05/(3e-05 + 1.6e-05 + 6.02e-05 + 5.71e-04) x 100. Rounding issues do not matter.

I have limited experience in excel, and help would be *very* appreciated.

Comment: The solution in your case is to create "helper" cells that hold the separated values. The helper cells can be right next to those values, or they can be WAY over in columns to the right (so they are not directly visible to a user), or even on a different sheet. To separate the values, use a formula like `=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))` and a similar formula to get the value between the parentheses. Now you can run your percentage calculations with those helper cells.

Comment: Fantastically simple solution - thank you so much! I've just put in some helper cells and all is working perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

If you have *limited experience in excel* I strongly suggest you to use helper columns so at least you know what are you doing. If you just ask for a *magic* superformula, any issue that may appear will block you and you won't be able to resolve it.

[image]

Column B got a formula to extract the non-bracket numbers (note my decimal separator is the comma, I guess yours is the dot). Also, because my Excel is spanish, my argument separator is `;` but probably yours is a comma:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(" ";A1)-1))
```

Same for column C but for bracketted numbers:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ";A1));"(";"");")";""))
```

Then cell B6 is just a sum up of numbers from column B and cell B7 is the calculus you said in your post:

```
=B6/(B1*100)
```

You can do all this without helper columns and a really complex formula, like I did in column D. It's an array formula so you must introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
=SUM(VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$4;SEARCH(" ";$A$1:$A$4)-1)))/(VALUE(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(" ";A1)-1))*100)
```

Anyways, I've uploaded the file to Gdrive so you can check the formulas (remember my decimal separator is the comma, not the dot, you'll need to replace commas manually)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKVs_vAjUhfIwXgRHNkLY4I4kowVUwAQ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true